# Forgot to push the commits

Tags: git, github

I'm working on a software project.
I use git / github.
I'm currently the only developer.
I usually work both from home place and from work place.
Before starting any session, I do a `git pull`, and when finished, a `git add . -A && git commit -m "my commit message" && git push --tags origin master` (I have a *gitaddcommitpush* alias for this).
Yesterday, after a working session, I forgot to *gitaddcommitpush*, from home :-(
[This](http://devopsreactions.tumblr.com/post/110711897062/forgot-to-push-the-commits) was my reaction whe I did realize it :-(
Now, the question:

*Which actions should I perform to be able to work today, at work (on a different section of the project than I was working yesterday from home, of course), to be able tomorrow @home to merge my changes of yesterday (from home) and today (from work) ?*

Comment: can't you logon to your home computer from work?

Comment: If you are working on the different section from the one that you changed at home,No need to worry,just work on other sections and push the changes.When u get back home pull them and push the changes that u did at home.

Comment: work on a separate branch, and later merge that with the @home one?

Comment: I would like to avoid the merge so he can keep a clean linear history.  Doing one rebase might be a bit involved, but after this everything stays the same.

Comment: @TemplateRex: no, it's offline, I can't...

Comment: @r2_d2: I'm afraid at home I will not be able to pull, since I have uncommitted changes... wrong?

Comment: Did u ever try to push commits without pulling? If you do so First it prompts to pull from the repo and then u can push the commits. You can always try a demo.

Comment: @r2_d2: probably I did never try, I just had a bad feeling... :-) I'll try your advise, tonight, for sure... If it works, it's the simplest solution...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you have been maintaining a nice linear Git workflow, I am going to suggest that you use rebasing to keep things the way they are.

You can simply work in the office today as usual, and commit your work.  When you return home to work, you can do a `git pull --rebase` to bring in the changes from work.  Your local branch will be behind the remote version by one or more commits.  Rebasing will make your home branch appear as if you actually did the last night's work on top of today's office work.  Take the following steps at home:

```
git commit -m 'Changes from last night which I forgot'
git pull --rebase origin master
```

There may be conflicts from this, but it is not too likely if you really worked on totally separate parts of the project in the office.

Here is a diagram showing what the state of your home and remote `master` branch will be *after* you commit your work at home from last night:

```
remote: A --- B --- C
                 \
local:              D
```

Here, commit `C` is the commit you made at work today, and commit `D` is the commit you will make tonight (for last night's work).  Now after you do `git pull --rebase origin master` the diagram will look like this:

```
remote: A --- B --- C
                     \
local:                D'
```

When you `git push` your changes in, the remote will receive a single new commit on top of what it had from work.  And when you go to work tomorrow, things will continue as they have been.

Comment: Thanks! Your explanation was very clear, to me, even if I'm a git newbe... :-( I'll try this at home! :-)

Comment: What do you think about r2_d2 advise (work normally and push changes; at home pull them and push the old changes...) ?

Comment: Git was designed to be very flexible and it should be able to handle your current setup.  That being said, you should make it a habit to commit and push your work often if for no other reason than it lets you backup your work.

Comment: I see... The only thing that curbs me from committing more often is the need to find a commit message every time... :-(